# How to have circular reasoning on Python modules?

Tags: python

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`.
In `file1`, I have three variables, two of which depend on variables in `file2`.
The converse is true for `file2`.  For instance, in `file`:

```
import file2
var1 = "yes"
var2 = file2.var1
var3 = file2.var2
```

In `file2` we have

```
import file1
var1 = "no"
var2 = file1.var1
var3 = file1.var2
```

I've tried moving the import statements around and introducing functions to call them in a specific order, and using functions to call them at a specific time. I'm at a loss. How can I make these files refer to each other in a circular way that would work for more than 3 variables?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: This seems like a breakdown in program design, not an issue with python.

Comment: I think whatever it is you're trying to do, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: The normal way to break a circular dependency is to move things to a third module, so that the two would depend on that third module, instead of each other.

Comment: You don't have a circular import alone, you are also having recursive references in your variables. Best would be not to put the imported varibles into local variables.

Comment: There's [some info about this in the official FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module). But basically, it's pretty simple: If you only use `import spam` (not `from spam import eggs`), and you don't do anything but define functions and classes in module-level code, there's never a problem. You do need to occasionally violate part of that, but then you know where you're violating it, and you have to make sure that the top-level code comes "last", which is only hard if you do it all over the place.

Comment: @KlausD.: the references aren't recursive: note that each variable depends on a lower-numbered variable in the other file.

Comment: @Prune recursion does not mean it is endless, just one module referencing the other until a condition is met.

Comment: Ah -- right.  module recursion, not datum recursion.

Comment: I am trying to make a number of modules where the prisoners dilemma can be played. Each person makes a file for whether to trust or betray their friend. I would iterate this ten times. However one common theme was to do what the other guy did last time. I was trying to find a fix for this if both people used this method.

Answer (score 1):

You've broken the paradigm of Python modules.  The concept is to have a hierarchy of dependency, or independence between modules.  Instead, you've created an artificial partition of a single dependency flow, and wondered why you have rotten communication between the two halves.

Instead, you need something more like this:

master.py:

```
var_1_1 = "yes"
var_2_1 = "no"
var_1_2 = var_2_1
var_2_2 = var_1_1
var_1_3 = var_2_2
var_2_3 = var_1_2
```

... and all of your other dependent files can import this.